# What happens to creatures on your person when you Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

If you choose to have your equipment meld with you and you are carrying a puppy in your backpack does the puppy meld along with your stuff or does it get kicked out?

If it melds with you and you decided to turn into a giant Frog since it's part of your body and form does it breath the same as you underwater or is it drowned when come back up after an hour?

Comment: Related: [Does magic armor resize with wild shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64370/33569), [Can a druid choose for some equipment to be worn while other equipment merges or is dropped when they go into Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140412/33569), [Is equipment that merges into the Druid's Wild Shape form weightless?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73145/33569), [Is there a limit to how much equipment can merge with your form when you Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70999/33569)

Comment: @V2Blast How are those not duplicates to this Too Broad question?

Comment: @NautArch: If you think something's a duplicate, feel free to vote to close it as such. (As diamond mods, we generally refrain from doing so unless it's really clear, as our votes can unilaterally close/reopen things.) Alternately, you can point out to the querent which parts are duplicates, and potentially edit them out to focus on the parts that aren't duplicates.

Comment: As is, this question as quite a few different questions at once here: Do (magic) items resize during wildshape? What happens to creatures inside carried equipment (do they meld, if so can they suffocate/drown?). The question regarding magic item resizing already has an answer here: "[Does magic armor resize with wild shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64370)". If you think that answer is satisfactory I would suggest editing that part out, leaving only the latter questions. If you feel your first question is still unanswered, I would suggest asking it separately, in a new question.

Comment: ty for the guidance I have tried to edit properly since there are no hard and fast rules about creatures but most answers have said undefined space for equipment and it's not damaged by the environment. I believe I have this fully answered. I think I can safely challenge the death of my puppy, for a possible scene rewrite.

Comment: @Stretch does carrying a puppy in the backpack has any purpose? what exactly? or was it a purely hypothetical question? (5e doesn't have many rules for carrying puppies in backpacks)

Comment: the party found a lair of wolves and decided to slay them even though I had fed them and negotiated safe passage, they wanted wolfskin cloaks. They even started slaying the puppies, so my character saved one and kept it hidden from the group. It became a distraction as the players kept trying to come up with reasons the characters would find out about it. So while they were fighting a Froghemoth, I changed to a giant frog swam to the lair and looted it puting things in my mouth. The characters had to flee and I showed up later with the treasure. So yeah real RP question.

Answer (score 4):

### The rules are intentionally silent, so you have options

The 5e does not have strict rules for this particular situation. It's a game about battles, heroes and monster slayers, not about pet carriers abusing their pets. The general rule for all corner cases — **it's up to the DM to decide**. The game developers [suggest](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/981248594836520960) to "go with what's best for your story":

> What happens when someone swallows a druid in a Tiny form? Is a druid fecund in beast form? The rules are intentionally silent on these corner cases, leaving adjudication to DMs. As always, I say go with what's best for your story.

If you are the player, ask your DM. If you are the DM, choose one from the four possible outcomes and stick to this ruling for the rest of the game:

1. The puppy is meld. That means it was a part of equipment, which I guess was not the way people run their games, but styles differ
2. The puppy is not meld, but the backpack is. That means the puppy is magically "ejected".
3. The whole backpack is not meld.
4. You cannot wild shape with the equipment meld, until a creature is inside it. A more restrictive option than 3.

Comment: What about a "the fly" type scenario? :P

Answer (score 2):

### The creature either falls or clings to your new form

Per the PHB, p. 67:

> You choose whether your **equipment** falls to the
>   ground in your space, merges into your new form, or
>   is worn by it.

No mention is made about creatures. It wouldn't make any sense if they were absorded into your body. It's definetely safe to assume they aren't directly affected by your shapechanging at all.

If your hawk pet is standing on your shoulder, it either stays firm on your "new" one, or it is forced into flying (or fall in a... Hawkward manner), depending on what beast you transform into. If you are carrying a puppy in your backpack, the backpack is absorbed into your new form and the puppy most likely falls on the ground. You can't suddenly transform while shaking hands with someone and having their hand fused with yours. You can burn it if you transform into a Fire Elemental, though. The creature suffers the indirect effect of being in contact with your body while it changes shape, but it doesn't get involved in your transformation.